# Unable to read input DOM element's value

Tags: javascript, html, dom, input

i have following html/JS code :

```
function controller()
{
    document.write(document.getElementById("name").value)   ;
    document.write(document.getElementById("id").value) ;
}
```

```
<input type="text" id="name"/>
<input type="text" id="id"/>
<input type="button" id="push" onclick="controller()"/>
```

**Problem** : when i click on push button `onclick` is fired and `controller` function is executed and i am able to retrieve value of element having id `name` but the second element having id `id`is not read and as a result i get the following error for second input element :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

I have been struggling for hours but i am unable to understand where i am making mistake can somebody help ?

Comment: do not use `document.write`

Comment: First `document.write` call will erase/replace the entire dom tree, As a result your upcoming element searches becomes invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script read the inputs values correctly, but when the first `document.write` statement execute it will override the body so when the script try to execute the second one it will find no input and return the error line :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Hope this helps.

```js
function controller()
{
  console.log(document.getElementById("name").value);
  console.log(document.getElementById("id").value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name"/>
<input type="text" id="id"/>
<input type="button" id="push" onclick="controller()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `document.write` is "clearing" the page.
The input's aren't anymore on the page, after the first `document.write`

Detailed Information can be found on the MDN under this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write

**Which states:**

> Note: as **document.write** writes to the document stream, calling
>   document.write on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls
>   document.open, which will clear the document

try instead `alert()` or `console.info()` or other functions that don't clear the document.

```js
function controller()
{
    alert(document.getElementById("name").value)   ;
    alert(document.getElementById("id").value) ;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
            <title>Insert title here</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <input type="text" id="name"/>
            <input type="text" id="id"/>
            <input type="button" id="push" onclick="controller()"/>
        </body>
    </html>
```

> tested on Win7 with chrome 51+

**Optional:**

If you want/have to use `document.write`, read first all values and that write them to the document.

```js
function controller()
{
    var firstField = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var secondField = document.getElementById("id").value;
    document.write(firstField);
    document.write(secondField);
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
            <title>Insert title here</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <input type="text" id="name"/>
            <input type="text" id="id"/>
            <input type="button" id="push" onclick="controller()"/>
        </body>
    </html>
```

> tested on Win7 with chrome 51+

---

***Info:*** The better way to attach Events is to attach them over an
Eventlistener here is an link to the `addEventListener` Reference
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that document.write erases the body you can instead use 'alert()' or add another element to dom and set its innerHTML to the values:

```
 function controller(){
  alert(document.getElementById("name").value)   ;
  alert(document.getElementById("id").value) ;
}
```

OR

```
<input type="text" id="name"/>
<input type="text" id="id"/>
<input type="button" id="push" onclick="controller()"/>
<div id="result"></div>
```

javascript

```
var ele=document.querySelector("#result");
function controller(){
  ele.innerHTML="Name :"+document.getElementById("name").value+"<br>Id: "+document.getElementById("id").value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.write(document.getElementById("name").value);` is replacing your entire dom, so the subsequent `getElementById` can't retrieve the input value. Store all of the values before you write them back to the document.

```
function controller(){
    var store = []; 
    store.push(document.getElementById("name").value);
    store.push(document.getElementById("name2").value);
    document.open();
    document.write(store);
    document.close(); 
}
```